# OAuth and Push with Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, push-notification

I'm trying to build a REST server using Express.js. The server will be consumed by mobile native client as well as from HTML/JS web clients. I want the HTML/JS web client to be served as static files only and and would interact using the REST apis.

I have two question here: 
1) How to integrate OAuth2 authentication to the service so that I can login using Facebook, Google, etc. I want the mobile as well as the web clients to use the same sets of APIs. 
2) How to send push notifications to mobile clients? Specifically to Apple mobile clients.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-oauth2-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a mobile client, it's usual that they request access tokens etc. from the OAuth provider (eg. google) - by using their mobile SDKs.

What they then do is send you this access token. You can go two ways about this - use the provider access token to directly authenticate every request (kind of ok, but not as robust) or use the provider access token to grant the mobile app your own auth token (or session, cookie, whatever you may be using).

The second way is, I think, more versatile.

And how to do it? `Passport.js` has modules for, say, google. Usually they plug a few endpoints in your app, such as:

```
/auth/google
```

and

```
/auth/google/callback
```

Now, the first one is usually what you use to initiate extenral auth process on your web or mobile web project. The `callback` url is where they hit you later with the access token - and that's what you will be using from your mobile app - they get the token, then hit your `/auth/:provider/callback` endpoint.

Comment: Zlatko, one more question. How should the mobile client pass the auth token using REST APIs? Which arguments/headers should be used? Also, should the redirect url be "/auth/:provider/callback" on the provider side?

Comment: Hmm. Those are a few questions, actually. 1. Pass the token as query param. Eg: `https://your-api.com/auth/google/callback?code=<authorization-code-you-got-from-google>` 2. It means it hits your API. You can change the `code` to `auth_token` or whatever. You can use post instead of get. But the above form is supported by passport.js and passport-google out of the box.